# Ubuntu 1604 and 1804 screen rendering issue

Tags: software-installation

In both of these installations, the rendering is sluggish and all screens render from the top. When I scroll, the screen slowly renders from the top. Is this an issue with the graphics driver?

Specs:
Nvidia 1050ti
i7 
16 gbs ram

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia driver?

Comment: yes I installed the nvidia driver. don't really know why this would help but I also got sddm

Comment: What version Nvidia driver? What shows up in `Software & Updates` `Additional Drivers`? What is sddm?

Comment: im using 390 currently. sddm is the simple desktop display manager (this was a blind attempt at fixing this issue)

Comment: Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD and see if the problem still occurs there. Does your computer have onboard video also?

Comment: I'm not having this issue when I run the live usb. My laptop has integrated graphics as well

Comment: To eliminate which graphic card is active, and which driver has the problem, temporarily remove the Nvidia, and retest the screen rendering. If it works fine, then the internal video and driver are working fine. Then the problem is with the Nvidia driver (or the card). When both are installed, how do you select which video card to use?